# How to correctly activate pipenv shell in zsh?

Tags: homebrew, zsh, pipenv

I'm currently working on a simple Python script and using `pipenv` to manage dependencies.

Here's the problem:

When running `pipenv shell` and then `python script.py`, I'm getting module not found errors for things that are definitely in Pipfile (e.g. requests).

Here's what's interesting:
I don't get these problems when I use `pipenv run python script.py` *and* I don't get these problems when I use `bash` instead of `zsh`, i.e. when I do:

```
bash
pipenv shell 
python script.py
```

the script runs happily and resolves the imports. I tried re-installing `pipenv` using Homebrew, but `zsh` still doesn't correctly activate my `pipenv` environment. Any ideas on how to get `pipenv` to work with `zsh` or why this would even be problematic?

**Using zsh:**

[image: zsh]

**Using bash:**

[image: bash]